# Why isn't WeakReference a struct?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, garbage-collection

As this article says: http://www.philosophicalgeek.com/2014/08/14/prefer-weakreferencet-to-weakreference/

> If you are using WeakReference at all, it likely means you are
>   somewhat memory conscious . In this case, allocating new
>   WeakReference objects will contribute extra, unnecessary memory
>   pressure.

So in this case, wouldn't it make more sense to make it a struct? And immutable while we're at it, and get rid of SetTarget().

Comment: Making it a struct causes side effects when passing it around, why do you think making it a struct would solve any of those issues?

Comment: Allocating structs also adds 'memory pressure'. Just in a different way. Probably not a better way.

Comment: Since `WeakReference` pre-dates C#2.0's generics, making collections of `WeakReference`-the-`struct`s would require a lot of boxing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`WeakReference`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.WeakReference.aspx) and [`WeakReference<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712738.aspx) classes both have finalizers, which [wouldn't be possible if they were structs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b.aspx).

If really necessary, you might be able to create your own custom weak-reference struct by making use of the [weak](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83y4ak54.aspx) variety of [`GCHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandle.aspx). (I believe, though I'm not certain, that `WeakReference` and `WeakReference<T>` use `GCHandle` internally, although their finalizers ensure that everything is cleaned-up properly. Your custom struct would need to take care of its own clean-up without resorting to finalizers.)

Comment: You're absolutely right, WeakReference seems to be nothing more than a wrapper on GCHandle, and it needs a finalizer to .Free() it, which actually kinda seems to be the only point of WeakReference.
They're surprinsgly simple: https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System/WeakReference_T.cs (OK the CoreCLR one is a bit funkier https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/src/System/WeakReferenceOfT.cs but it's mostly Contract fluff).

Comment: So yeah, I didn't know it was possible to get a weak handle directly, so I can just create my own GCHandle<T> wrapper struct, with the same TryGetTarget (and do without the trackResurrection thing!)... just gotta handle the Free()!